# Creating multiple identical threads in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

What I woul dlike to do is to create multiple threads calling the same method with slightly different arguments each time, like this:

```
x = 1
argument = 3
while x <= 10 do #10 is the number of desired threads
    Thread.new{
        puts do.stuff(argument)
    }.join
    x += 1
    arguments += 1
end
```

My problem is that this code causes the main thread to stop until the declared thread is finished. Is there any way I can create these threads so that they will run concurrently?
Thanks.

Comment: Note that, in MRI, threads will run concurrently, but never in parallel due to the [global interpreter lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) (GIL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is joining (waiting the thread to be terminated; causing the 2nd thread run after 1st thread finish, 3rd thread run after 2nd thread, ...) inside the loop.

Create threads, and wait them outside the loop.

```
arguments = "3"
threads = 10.times.map {
  Thread.new {
    puts do.stuff(arguments)
  }
  # NOTE: no join here.
}
threads.each { |t| t.join }
```

Comment: What if I wanted to do something like thread A calls do.stuff(3), then create 10 more threads like it while adding one to the argument?

Comment: @ApocalypticSnail, I don't get what you mean. Could you post it as a separate questiin?

Comment: I may not have stated it clearly above. What I want to do is to call the same method multiple times with different arguments in different threads.

Comment: @ApocalypticSnail, inside the thread block, use a loop construct (while, for, each, times, ...)

Comment: From my understanding, it looks this code creates an array with a size of 10 with each slot being filled by Thread.new, which you then execute with threads.each. However, for some reason the threads{} block will run regardless of whether or not it is executed. What is happening?

Comment: @ApocalypticSnail, That's the way `Thread::new` works. The block is executed in a new thread. There's no explicit execute, it is executed if the thread object is created.